# How to set docker file in jenkin pipeline stage

Tags: jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I have a simple JenkinsFile uploaded in my git repo

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Initialize'){
            def dockerHome = tool 'myDocker'
            env.PATH = "${dockerHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"
            }
        stage('Push to Docker Registry'){
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'dockerHubAccount', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
        pushToImage(CONTAINER_NAME, CONTAINER_TAG, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    }  
        }
    }
}
```

In jenkins, i have created a pipeline project and just passed path to my git repo.
myDocker is defined in global tool configuration.
dockerhub credentials are defined in jenkins->credentials.

On build , i am getting this:

```
Started by user ********
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/*****/*****.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 4: Not a valid stage section definition: "def dockerHome = tool 'myDocker'". Some extra configuration is required. @ line 4, column 9.
           stage('Initialize'){
           ^

WorkflowScript: 4: Not a valid stage section definition: "env.PATH = "${dockerHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"". Some extra configuration is required. @ line 4, column 9.
           stage('Initialize'){
           ^

WorkflowScript: 8: Unknown stage section "withCredentials". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block. @ line 8, column 9.
           stage('Push to Docker Registry'){
           ^

WorkflowScript: 4: Expected one of "steps", "stages", or "parallel" for stage "Initialize" @ line 4, column 9.
           stage('Initialize'){
           ^

WorkflowScript: 8: Expected one of "steps", "stages", or "parallel" for stage "Push to Docker Registry" @ line 8, column 9.
           stage('Push to Docker Registry'){
           ^

5 errors

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:327)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am sure , i am making any small mistake. Please redirect me to right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your code within steps inside a stage like below.

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Initialize'){
        steps {
                def dockerHome = tool 'myDocker'
                env.PATH = "${dockerHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"                }
        }
    stage('Push to Docker Registry'){
        steps {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'dockerHubAccount', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {                
            pushToImage(CONTAINER_NAME, CONTAINER_TAG, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
            }            
        }  
    }
}}
```

Documentation Link. [Creating Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/)